# No such file or directory 'nltk_data/corpora/stopwords/English' when using colab

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, google-colaboratory

First of all I am using Google colab for the work and
I have downloaded nltk stopwords for English with following:

```
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

The download was successful

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /root/nltk_data...
```

but when I run `stop = stopwords.words('English')`

I am getting `OSError: No such file or directory: '/root/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords/English'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## TL;DR

The `English` should be in lowercase =)

See: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tNt0Ifom-h4OnFBBZpLndYCEPDU598jE

## In Code

```
# Downloads the data.
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')


# Using the stopwords.
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Initialize the stopwords
stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
```